# How to do "success rate" in kibana visualization?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Lets say I have a boolean field `success`. Over the course of 1 week I have 100 documents. How can I get a visualization for success rate in kibana? Basically `count success where true` / `count success`. I see a bunch of visualization options but can't figure out any that do this.

Comment: have you had any success with my suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could set up a simple pie chart where you do a terms aggregation on the success field. Additionally you can configure a time interval for the past 7 days.

This will give you the percentage of each value of the success field.